# Android design library TabLayout background issues

Tags: android, ripple, android-design-library

When I setup the tabBackground attribute of the "22.2.0 Android design library"  TabLayout (android.support.design.widget.TabLayout) two problems appear :

- The ripple effect in the tabs is lost
- The tab indicator disappears.

This occurs on both Lollipop and Kitkat devices.

Without the tabBackground settings, both ripple effect and tab indicator work but the background has a default color that is different from the toobar, which is not exactly conform to the material design guidelines.

Please find below the XML :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabBackground = "?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` instead of `app:tabBackground = "?attr/colorPrimary"`.

If you have a dark primary color, you may also want to change the theme to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`. This makes the text and the ripple color white.

Full example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

Comment: Great. It works now except that I don't have the ripple effect on the KitKat device. Do you know whether or not  the ripple effect in  Android design library TabLayout  is supposed to be ported to KitKat " ? Thanks.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I think ripples only work on 5.0 and above in the design library.

Comment: `android:background="@color/someColor"`  also works with `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` in case someone is wondering